# Why doesn't the summaryRow of my dataTable display?

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, primefaces

I have a **dataTable** on my JSF page:

```
<p:dataTable id="dataCabecera" value="#{cargaHorariaController.listaActivDoc}" var="listaActDoc"
             rowKey="#{listaActDoc.pzptcabperjactPK.pzptcabperjactActividad}" selectionMode="single"
             selection="#{cargaHorariaController.listaActivSelected}">
    <p:column headerText="Actividad" style="width: 35%">
        <p:outputLabel value="#{listaActDoc.pzptcabperjactPK.pzptcabperjactActividad} - #{cargaHorariaController.descActiv(listaActDoc.pzptcabperjactPK.pzptcabperjactActividad)}"/>
    </p:column>

    <p:column headerText="Horas" style="width: 15%">
        <p:outputLabel value="#{listaActDoc.pzptcabperjactHoras}" />
    </p:column>

    <p:column headerText="" style="width: 20%">
        <p:commandLink id="cmdSubacti" process="dataCabecera"
                       style="margin:0px" title="subactividad" value="Ver Subactividad"
                       action="#{cargaHorariaController.consultarSubactividadesDoc()}" update=":formPrincipal:formPrincipal1:pnlDet">
            <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{listaActDoc}" target="#{cargaHorariaController.activSelected}"/>
        </p:commandLink>
    </p:column>

    <p:column headerText="" style="width: 30%">
        <p:commandButton value="Actualizar" type="button" id="actiActu" action="#{cargaHorariaController.actualizar()}" onclick="PF('wdlgActualizar').show()" />
        <p:spacer width="15px" height="0px"> </p:spacer>
        <p:commandButton value="Eliminar" id="actiEli" ajax="false">
            <p:confirm header="Eliminar actividad" message="Está seguro que desea eliminar esta actividad?" icon="ui-icon-alert" />
        </p:commandButton>
        <p:confirmDialog global="true" showEffect="fade" hideEffect="fade" style="font-size: 11px; text-height: font-size; text-align: left; font-weight: bold">
            <div align="center">
                <p:commandButton value="Sí" type="button" styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-yes" icon="ui-icon-check" />
                <p:commandButton value="Cancelar" type="button" styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-no CyanButton" icon="ui-icon-close" />
            </div>
        </p:confirmDialog>
    </p:column>
    <p:summaryRow>
        <p:column colspan="1" style="text-align: right">
            <p:outputLabel value="Total:" />
        </p:column>
        <p:column colspan="2" style="text-align: left">
            <p:outputLabel value="#{cargaHorariaController.horasAct}" />
        </p:column>
    </p:summaryRow>
</p:dataTable>
```

I want the sum of the column "**Horas**" at the bottom of the table, but the **summaryRow** doesn't appear:

[image: table]

I have also the same problem with icons in my buttons (jQueryUI icons and Font Awesome icons).
How can I fix it?

**Edited:** I used h:outputText and I changed the colspan properties so now they add up to 4, but the same result: no p:summaryRow. I called horasAct because that variable has the result of the sum.

Answer (score 0):

First for display information it's better to use a `h:outputText` component. Because a `p:outputLabel` component need to bind a label with a input field.

It gives some advantages for example:

- If you mark a input field like required neer label for this field will display '*' symbol
- Value from label will use in the **Faces Messages**

Second about your `p:summaryRow`. In the `p:dataTable` you have four columns but in columns in the `p:summaryRow` colSpan properties in total don't give 4 (only 3).

Also you said that want to sum values from the "Horas" column. But call

`#{cargaHorariaController.horasAct}` instead of `#{listaActDoc.pzptcabperjactHoras}`

**Update**

You need to add a `sortBy` property then a `summaryRow` will display. But this component calculate a sum of a column value for same rows. You can see more examples [here](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/summaryRow.xhtml) just to try sort a table by different columns.

I think you should use a [`columnGroup`](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/group.xhtml) component and add a footer for your table. This component add only one row to the bottom of your table and you can output there sum for horas column.